# Apache DBUtils - Stored Procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, apache-commons

Is it possible for apache dbutils library to invoke oracle stored procedures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
QueryRunner run = JDBCConnectionFactory.getQueryRunner(database);
Connection conn = run.getDataSource().getConnection();
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{CALL procName()}");
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
JongoResultSetHandler handler = new JongoResultSetHandler(true);
return handler.handle(rs);
```

Here I use a QueryRunner instance to obtain its connection since this is managed by DBUtils. Take in mind closing connection, exception handling, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In a nutshell, it's not possible as none of the `AbstractQueryRunner` implementations doesn't support stored procedure call whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as it just uses JDBC - you will need a [JDBC driver for Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)

Comment: What would the API invocation for CallableStatements be? I don't see CallableStatement usages in dbUtils source code.

Comment: It does not deal with Statements at all it hides that from you - if you need CallableStatements use plain JDBC to call - although ResultSetHandler could still be used

Comment: Thanks Mark , but since CallableStatement would be required to call a stored procedure wouldn't dbutils support it?