# Calling a stored procedure using apache DBUtils

Tags: java, callable-statement, apache-commons-dbutils

I cannot find how we can use DBUtils to invoke callable statements

Can we some how specify which all fields are inputs and which all re outputs ?

Comment: You can find one answer to your question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742224/apache-dbutils-stored-procedure)

Comment: Can we use dbutils to specify in and out parameters ?

Comment: DBUtils is a light jar to wrap Database Operator, no function with stored procedure, please use JDBC Operator of  Connection(CallableStatement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a `CallableStatement`

```
Connection con = ...; // get the connection
CallableStatement callStatement = con.prepareCall("{CALL yourStoredProcedure()}");
ResultSet rs = callStatement.executeQuery();
// do what you need to do
```

Comment: Here we are not using DButils

Comment: Can we use dbutils to specify  in and out parameters ?